# How to create sections with React

Tags: html, reactjs

How should I create section in my html: create one root div and fill it with components like `<Header/>` and `<Footer/>` or create a few html section and fill each one with corresponding components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am finding that it is a lot cleaner for me to have a single root component that holds the header and footer components like so:

```
class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Header />

      {this.props.children}

      <Footer />
    );
  }
}
```

This allows me to render my components without having to bloat them with the header and footer components. It is also annoying to me that I have to include the header and footer components every time I create a new page if I don't use this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Because React components are composable, either approach works well, depending on how complex your header/footer is. If they are simple enough, this works (I'm using stateless functional components for simplicity) :

```
function Root() {
  return (
    <div>
     <header>/* simple header content */</header>
     <footer> /* simple footer content */</footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

but as the content inside your `header` and `footer` tags becomes more complex, you can factor them into their own components to keep your files small and readable:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <header>
     // complex content
    </header>
  )
}
// Similar for Footer component
function Root() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header/>
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Without more information from you (like a sample header and footer) we can't give more advice.